# What command can read email mailbox file and produce output to stdout?

Tags: email, mail, mutt, email-client

Is there any CLI email client/program which can read email mailbox file (with single email message) and produce output to stdout main headers and text?

```
$ mailcmd < email.file
From: some@email.com
Subject: some subject
Message text: Hello world!
```

Comment: I don't uinderstand, what's the content of `email.file`?

Comment: `email.file` has the same format as `/var/mail/user` mailbox file. And `email.file` contains single email message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
mutt -f email.file -e "push <decode-save><Return><Return><quit><Return>"
```

**-e** key execute following command
**push** add key sequences to the keyboard buffer

As result I get file with main headers and plain text from raw mailbox file

When I execute the script under cron or procmail:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && screen -dm mutt -f email.file -e "push <decode-save><Return><Return><quit><Return>"
```